# Terraform - OAC Errors in in CloudFront Distribution setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, terraform-provider-aws

I am working though the well known Cloud Resume Challenge and have a lot of my AWS setup automated with Terraform now but I am stuck on the OAC portion of the CloudFront distribution setup and haven't found much online/in documentation. Here's my current Terraform script:

```
locals {
    s3_origin_id = aws_s3_bucket.gjd_crc_prod_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "crc_cf_oac" {
    name = local.s3_origin_id
    origin_access_control_origin_type = "s3"
    signing_behavior = "always"
    signing_protocol = "sigv4"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "crc_prod_cfdist" {
    origin {
        s3_origin_config {
            origin_access_identity = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.crc_cf_oac.id
        }
      domain_name = local.s3_origin_id
      origin_id = local.s3_origin_id
    }
    
    enabled = true
    is_ipv6_enabled = true
    default_root_object = "index.html"

    default_cache_behavior {
        cache_policy_id = "658327ea-f89d-4fab-a63d-7e88639e58f6"
        allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
        cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
        target_origin_id = local.s3_origin_id
        viewer_protocol_policy = "https-only"
        compress = true
    }

    viewer_certificate {
      cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    }

    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
          restriction_type = "none"
          locations = []
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting when I go to apply via Terraform:

```
aws_cloudfront_distribution.crc_prod_cfdist: Modifying... [id=E2F87SH1SP8PTO]
╷
│ Error: updating CloudFront Distribution (E2F87SH1SP8PTO): InvalidOriginAccessIdentity: The specified origin access identity does not exist or is not valid.
│       status code: 400, request id: 927f5e89-4ee0-4fa0-99c6-776547f41e03
│
│   with aws_cloudfront_distribution.crc_prod_cfdist,
│   on cloudfront.tf line 12, in resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "crc_prod_cfdist":
│   12: resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "crc_prod_cfdist" {
│
╵
```

All of the documentation I can find (which is not much tbh) is that OAC should be as simple as establishing an OAC resource and then referencing the ID of said resource in the distribution but it's acting like it doesn't exist/hasn't been created yet.

Any thoughts? I hate to have to resort to legacy/deprecated options.

Edit: wanted to add that this is just the CloudFront.tf script. I'm not sure what proper protocol is but I like keeping the services in separate scripts for readability. Happy to share any others if it seems necessary (such as the S3 bucket script which is fully functional)

Edit: SOLVED. Here's the updated code that uses an OAC resource but referenced using OAI:

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "crc_prod_cfdist" {
    origin {
        origin_access_control_id = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.crc_cf_oac.id
        domain_name = local.s3_origin_id
        origin_id = local.s3_origin_id
    }
```

Comment: So you want CloudFront to access your S3 bucket which is configured as a static website?

Comment: So the S3 bucket is not configured as a static site since that's no longer required when using AWS. The setup works when configured through the portal so I know that much is true but otherwise yeah, I want the CloudFront distribution accessing an S3 bucket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control`, you should be using `aws_cloudfront_origin_access_identity`.

Comment: OAI was deprecated in favor of OAC: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/08/amazon-cloudfront-origin-access-control/

Comment: OMG, I see now. I've edited the main post with updated piece of functional code. How confusing/annoying.